# Передача переменных из javascript в php

Tags: javascript

Передача переменных из javascript в php. Пробовал так, но не получается.

```
<html>
<form method="POST">
<script type="text/javascript">

alert('авторизация прошла не удачно, просим снова написать логин и пароль');

var username = prompt ('логин','email');

var userpass = prompt ('пароль','пароль');

</script>
</html>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpass = $_POST['userpass'];

echo $username;
echo $userpass;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не требуется асинхронно предавать(без перезагрузки). То можно сделать примерно так

```
 var newF = document.createElement("form"); 
    newF.action = "url-на-php-скрипт/"; 
    newF.method = 'POST';
    newF.id = 'newform';

    var qwertyinput = document.createElement("input");
    typeinput.name = 'type';
    typeinput.type = 'hidden'; 
    typeinput.value = username ; 
newF.appendChild(qwertyinput );

var asdfinput = document.createElement("input");
mmoinput.name = 'mmo';
mmoinput.type = 'hidden'; 
mmoinput.value = userpass ; 
newF.appendChild(asdfinput );  
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newF);  
newF.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый шаг вы сделали, но эти переменные остались у вас на локальной машине, так как JavaScript по умолчанию не будет их никуда передавать.

Чтобы отдать их скрипту на php для обработки необходимо сформировать POST запрос.
Делается это с помощью [AJAX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), а именно HttpRequest.